# How to change object type of snakemake.input/ snakemake.output inside a script to create directories?

Tags: python, oop, operating-system, bioinformatics, snakemake

I'm attempting to use a python script from within snakemake using the following rule

```
rule split_cells:
input:
    base_path + "{sample}_aligned/{sample}Mito.sortedByCoord.out.bam"
output:
    base_path + "{sample}_aligned/Cellular_Mitos/"
conda:
    "DsmPipeline2.yaml" # used for running pysam
script:
    "scripts/split.py"
```

In the script I want it to create the output directory which is stated in the rule above. I try to do this by using os.mkdir to create the snakemake.output directory. When I did this, os.mkdir threw an error, stating:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InputFiles
```

To navigate this issue I tried changing the type of snakemake.output to a str, using the following code within split.py

```
import pysam
import sys
import os


print(snakemake.output)
print(type(snakemake.output))
print(type(str(snakemake.output)))
# create the output directory
os.mkdir(str(snakemake.output))
```

I tried to print the types all the way through to diagnose the issue and got the following output as expected:

```
/rds/general/user/rest_of_file_path
<class 'snakemake.io.OutputFiles'>
<class 'str'>
```

Yet os.mkdir still throws a type error having detected the type as being InputFiles

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InputFiles
```

Firstly, in general python terms, how does one explain this behaviour? Secondly, how do I actually convert the type of instances of snakemake.input/snakemake.output objects inside scripts in snakemake, and moreover, how do I get scripts to use these snakemake objects to create directories?

Comment: The 'input' is a list-like object. 'os.mkdir(snakemake.output[0])' should do the trick

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem: I think that if your output is a directory, you should wrap it in `directory()`.

Comment: From your output, it seems there was no problem converting the `OutputFiles` object into a `str`. I find it puzzling that you have this `TypeError`, since what you feed to `os.mkdir` is a `str`. Are you certain this error happens upon execution of `os.mkdir`?

Comment: Also, I notice the error complains about `InputFiles`, not about `OutputFiles`. The problem may happen somewhere else. You should probably give more details about your script and about your snakefile.